# How to get next commit to apply when using git rebase?

Tags: git

I am now in the middle of branch rebase (conflicts stage) and I want to skip some commits using git rebase --skip. However I am wondering how to check what commit is actually being applied to the workspace (the conflicting one). Is there a simple way to do this? Google did not help this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the file `.git/rebase-apply/original-commit` which should contains the hash of the commit which generates the conflict.

Comment: It is helpful but it contains only hash. I noticed that when using pure command line (not SourceTree or other GUI app) command "git rebase --continue" exactly shows which commits (names!) are currently being applied and which failed bacause of conficts.

Comment: with the hash, using `git log <hash>` will give you all the info you want on the commit